# use grouping variable as input in group_map() function

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, purrr

I have a data frame of 30 years of a response variable. I want to write a code that will subset that df into "x" number of years "n" times, and run a regression of the response in all of those subsets.

So if we started with 30 years, x=5 & n=2, we would end with 2 regressions, each using 5 random years out of the available 30. I wrote a function for that here:

```
# build df
df = data.frame(year=c(1:30),
                response = runif(30,1,100))



# create function
subsample <- function(df, x, n ){
  df %>%
    # collaplse the tibble
    nest(data=everything()) %>%

    # repeat the tibble for number of simulations
    slice(rep(1:n(), each = n)) %>%

    # add group number, which will be the "nth" trial
    mutate(group = c(1:n)) %>%

    # expand data
    unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%

    # group by group number, then subsample n times from each group
    group_by(group) %>%
    group_map(~ sample_n(.x, x, replace = F)) %>%

    # stitch back together and add group number col back
    bind_rows(.id="trial") %>%

    # arrange by group and year
    mutate(trial=as.numeric(trial)) %>%
    arrange(trial,year) %>%

    # group by subsample and run regression
    group_by(trial) %>%

    do({
      mod = lm(response ~ year, data = .)
      data.frame(Intercept = coef(mod)[1],
                 Slope = coef(mod)[2])
    }) 
}


# test function
subsample(df, x=5, n=2)


# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   simulation [2]
      trial   Intercept  Slope
       <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1          1      48.5 -0.895
2          2      35.4 -0.275
```

Great, so that works, and we get two regressions (all I want is slope and intercept) each using a subset of 5 out of 30 years.

However, now I want to do this with every possible combination of years (so x = c(2:30)), ending with a df that should look like this

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   number_of_years    trial   Intercept  Slope
        <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1         2             1      48.5 -0.895
2         2             2      35.4 -0.275
3         3             1      55.2  0.333
4         3             2      34.1  0.224
5         4             1      63.2 -0.359
6         4             2      45.5 -0.241
7         5             1      43.1  0.257
8         5             2      37.9 -0.657
9         6             1      51.0 -0.456
10        6             2      65.6  0.126
```

This would be showing regression values of 2 trials ("n") each using 2 random years (number_of_years, "x"), then 2 trials using 3 random years, 4 random years, etc... all the way until 30.

So I tried to follow the same logic as above, but now trying `map_group()` with the custom function that I built:

```
df %>%
  # collaplse the tibble
  nest(data=everything()) %>%

  # repeat the tibble for the number of simulations we want to test (29, in this case)
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = (nrow(df)-1))) %>%

  # add column for number out of total and unnest
  mutate(number_of_years = c(2:(nrow(.)+1))) %>% 
  select(number_of_years,data) %>%  #reorder
  unnest(cols =c(data)) %>%

  # group by out of total
  group_by(number_of_years) %>%

  group_map( ~ subsample(.x, x=5, n=2,))
  ### this is the problematic line! 
  ### this is giving us 2 trials (n=2) of a regression, each using 
  ### x=5 years of sampling. but instead of x=5 years, I want x=number_of_years
  ### so x should be the same as the grouping variable.
```

So the problem here is, since my subsample() function needs 3 inputs (df, x, n), I need to figure out how to make "x" the same as the grouping variable for the dataset. x should be (number_of_years). I've tried to do `group_map( ~ subsample(.x,.x$number_of_years,2)` and variations like that, but I can't figure out how to make it return 30 tibbles of 2 trials each, meaning 2 regressions of subsamples of the original df, but each one using a different number of years to calculate the regression.

I would like to stay in the tidyverse/ dplyr/ purr workflow if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `map(2:10, ~ subsample(df, x = 5, n = .x))`